# cmake_binary_dir changes inside subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I have this in my top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmakebuild/bin)
MESSAGE("Value is: \n${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ")
add_subdirectory("sub/subA")
```

In the subdirectory CMakeLists.txt, I have this

```
MESSAGE("SUBDIR Value is: \n${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ")
```

But the output of `cmake` is

```
Value is:
/home/me/myproj/cmakebuild/bin
SUBDIR Value is:
/home/me/myproj/cmakebuild
```

Why is the /bin at the end not there?

Comment: `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")`
and using EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH instead of CMAKE_BINARY_DIR seems to work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never set variables** like `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` - CMake sets them automatically and doesn't expect them to be changed outside.

Setting these variable just confuse CMake, and things become very strange.

Comment: I will try to follow that advice.  Can you answer the question please?
BTW, lots of projects do set CMAKE_BINARY_DIR, I didn't just make it up.  Any reference or explanation for why you should "Never set them" ?

Comment: This is already an answer - you try to set the variable, and observe strange behavior. It is like "Undefined behavior" in some programming languages. As for reference about "never set them".. [Documentation for given variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html) specifies value of the variable. One can guess that other values are not OK... Anywhere, I saw other questions, which set such variable and observe problems when build simple executable.